# iOS Camera focus value

Tags: iphone, camera, focus

Is there any way to get the focus value from iPhone camera with autofocus?

I want to use this data to calculate the distance from iPhone to an object in focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously this is an old question, but as there is an option to get a "lense value" since iOS8 it should appear here.

Since iOS8 you can get the focus value from the lense by key-value observing `lensPosition`. It is a property of the `AVCaptureDevice` class which is part of the `AVFoundation` framework.

So somewhere in your camera class set the observer:

```
// Assuming _device is an object of the `AVCaptureDevice` class
[_device addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"lensPosition" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

And in the class you used as observer:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"lensPosition"]) {
        NSLog(@"change: %@", change);
        NSLog(@"lens position: %f", [change[@"new"] floatValue]);
    }
}
```

The position of the lens will be displayed as a scalar value from 0 to 1.
Also you can set the lens position manually. You can find out more about [managing the lens position](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW150) in the Apple Documentation.

Finally as with all [key-value observer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH16) don't forget to remove the observer.

NOTE: The lens is a mechanical part in the device and focusing is done by moving the lens via a spring. So values differ depending on the device and situation.

Comment: What's the best way to transform lens position values into distance and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is such a thing as a focus value.

Comment: To clarify: obviously there is such a thing as a focus value, and it's stored on the internal memory of the camera's onboard controller wafer. But @Oscar is correct that that number is not exposed by Cocoa Touch. I don't know if a jailbroken iPhone could access the value or not.