# find distance from an object to our iPhonecamera in an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS Camera focus value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465198/ios-camera-focus-value)

My client needs an app which works like this . When I focus Camera on an object it measures the distance between camera and focused Object . I don't have any Idea how to do this . Kindly help me to do this . Let me know if you need any details or question not clear .

Thanks and Regards,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

Hey you using iphone or radar system ?

Tell your client it will come in ios 7 .

Comment: There is no feature like that !!!

Comment: Are you sure It is not possible?

Comment: ya i am sure it is not possible from camera you can detect whole things of an object like its color , eyes detection, mouth etc you can find but distance not !!!